# How does gradient descent deal with regions where the function doesn't exist?

Tags: gradient-descent

How do implementations of gradient descent typically handle functions that have regions where the function or its derivative isn't defined? Do they attempt to "edge" around the undefined region, or attempt to jump over it? If gradient descent can't be applied to those kinds of functions, then what kinds of optimization techniques are used?

For example, consider trying to set the side lengths of a triangle in order to make the area it covers best fit around some given shape:

- the parameters of this optimization problem are the side lengths of the triangle
- the cost function is some function of the overlap of the triangle's area with a given shape.

There are certain regions of the parameter space for which the area of the triangle isn't defined, like when one side length is greater than the sum of the other two. If a gradient descent optimizer blindly attempts to optimize the cost function over this parameter space, it could run into one of those regions.

How are cost functions like that handled by optimizers?

Comment: I think one strategy is to transform the inputs into an unrestricted space so that we can freely perform the computations. For example, if a parameter is positive definite, we often model the log of that parameter.  However, I'm not sure if this is what happens in applications where gradient descent is used. Did you have any specific examples?

Comment: @Demetri one example is setting the side lengths of a triangle in order to make its area best fit some other given area. There are certain sets of lengths that aren't allowed, like when one side length is larger than the sum of the other two. The cost function and its derivative (which depends on the area of the triangle) would be undefined in that case.

Comment: In instances like that, the parameters are likely transformed into an unconstrained space, as I have previously mentioned.  If you provide some more details, I'll provide an answer below.

Comment: I updated the question with the triangle example. I'm not sure whether parameters can be transformed in these cases, but if so I'm very interested in hearing how that could be done!